# Formatar o tamanho da célula em arquivos .csv

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Gero esse csv

```
public ActionResult geraExcel()
        {
            List<vwFinancingReportViewModel> lista = new List<vwFinancingReportViewModel>();
            lista = dadosPlanilha();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("Status;Nro.Pessoal;Nome Completo;Grade;Nro.Solicitação;Data Financiamento;" + 
                "Ano Fabric.;Modelo;Chassi;Valor Bem;Valor Financiado;Status Solicitação;Status Pagamento;" +
                "Valor Parcela;Juros;ReembolsoKM;Reembolso Depreciação;Sequencia;Data Pagamento\r\n");
            foreach(var item in lista)
            {
                sb.Append(item.valuepayment.ToString() + ";" + item.chassi.ToString() + ";" + item.solicitationid.ToString() + "\r\n");

            }
            //sb.Append("Eduardo;11111\r\n");
            //sb.Append("Coutinho;22222\r\n");

            HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "ReportFinanciamentoRH.csv"));

            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";
            HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

            HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());

            HttpContext.Response.End();

            return null;
        }
```

Consigo aumentar o tamanho da célula, de forma que ao abrir o arquivo via excel, o nome(cabeçalho) das colunas possam aparecer corretamente, sem a necessidade de eu aumentar a célula?

Comment: um arquivo csv é um arquivo *plain text*, sem formatação, não faria muito sentido formatar o tamanho da célula. Talvez se aumentar o tamanho do texto do cabeçalho a coluna aumente tb, mas de novo, não faz sentido, porque um arquivo csv não é pra leitura, mas pra importação

Comment: Entendi, @RicardoPontual, mas muita gente o usa para exportar planilha e etc.. Tentei fazendo uma planilha e não estou conseguindo, por isso eu mudei para csv, apenas para ganhar tempo.

Comment: Sim, como arquivo de exportação, se importar ele no Excel vai poder formatar normalmente. Tentou adicionar espaços no nome da coluna no cabeçalho?

Comment: Sim, possuo nomes grandes, como **Nome Completo** e mesmo assim ele vem no tamanho padrão do excel. Mas não vejo isso como um problema sério. De qualquer forma, obgd pela dica.